# How to create grid style icons using ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, gridview, icons, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPagerLibrary which is used for my main view. The main view has 2 pages (horizontally scrolling to the right and left). What I would like to do is add a grid style icons to each of the pages, much like the android home screen or the new applications screen in Ice Cream Sandwich. I have the ViewPager implemented properly and I can swipe between left and right but I am confused on how exactly I can add the grid and icons to each of the pages. Of course, each page will feature a different set of icons. I have no idea where to start, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**This is my main xml:**

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_main"
            />
    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

**and this is my main activity:**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity
{

    PagerAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initialisePaging();

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator = indicator;
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        indicator.setSnap(true);
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MainScreenFragmentOne.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MainScreenFragmentTwo.class.getName()));
        mAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    }


    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am adding two pages (fragments). I would really like to not have a class for each fragments, rather I would like to have 1 class where I can create icons for both pages.

Can anyone help?

Thanks guys!